# Invalid operands 'Dictionary' and 'Array' in operator '+'.Godot3.5

Tags: godot

I am using v3.5.stable.official [991bb6ac7] Godot Engine I was also using version 3.4, that is also the reason I have decided to update, since I can't get passed by that error.

`Invalid operands 'Dictionary' and 'Array' in operator '+'`

```
extends Area2D

onready var timer = $Timer
onready var plant = $Sprite
var stage = 0
var PlantNum

func _ready():
    PlantNum = Game.Plot.size()
    Game.Plot += [{
        "Seed": "Corn",
        "TimeLeft": timer.time_left,
        "Stage": stage,
    }]
    
    Utils.save_game()
    timer.start()
    plant.frame = 1
```

This piece of code is for my game project that I am trying to make. The code serves for the save and load, so that the plants stage will stay the same as when I join again.

The global script which is connected to the upper one.

```
extends Node

var Plot = [
    {
        "Seed":"",
        "TimeLeft":0,
        "Stage":0,
    },
]
```

`Expected output`

```
[{Seed:, Stage:0, TimeLeft:0}, {Seed:Corn ,Stage:0, TimeLeft:0}]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `Game.Plot` a dictionary? If so, what do you expect adding an array to it to accomplish? Can you give us expected input and output?

Comment: Every time I plant the corn I would like to add that to dictionary. I will update the thread, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are getting that particular error. My first guess is that somewhere along the line the type was lost… Either somewhere you set a `Dictionary` to `Plot` (after all, it is Variant), or we are looking at a bug in Godot.

Either way, you can declare Plot as an `Array` (so it is not Variant). Either implicitly:

```
var Plot := [
    {
        "Seed":"",
        "TimeLeft":0,
        "Stage":0,
    },
]
```

Or explicitly

```
var Plot:Array = [
    {
        "Seed":"",
        "TimeLeft":0,
        "Stage":0,
    },
]
```

---

On the other hand, using using `append_array` is better than `+=` (it does not allocate a new `Array`), so I would prefer that:

```
Game.Plot.apppend_array([{
    "Seed": "Corn",
    "TimeLeft": timer.time_left,
    "Stage": stage,
}])
```

Furthermore, you are just adding one element, thus you can use `append`:

```
Game.Plot.apppend({
    "Seed": "Corn",
    "TimeLeft": timer.time_left,
    "Stage": stage,
})
```

Comment: I tried fixing the error by doing as you said, alternative to +=, but I got a new error by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the post.

I have done this

```
func _ready():
PlantNum = Game.Plot.size()
Game.Plot.append({
    "Seed": "Corn",
    "TimeLeft": timer.time_left,
    "Stage": stage,
})
```

And this,

```
var Plot := [
{
    "Seed":"",
    "TimeLeft":0,
    "Stage":0,
}]
```

I got a new error by doing so,

```
Parser Error: The assigned value's type (Dictionary) doesn't match the variable's type (Array).

func _ready():
var date = OS.get_datetime()
Game.Plot = OS.get_datetime() # Error is in this line.
self.text = "Time: " + str(date["hour"]) + " : " + str(date["minute"])
```

Comment: That makes sense. Now that you have specified (implicitly) that `Plot ` is an array, you cannot set to it the result of `OS.get_datetime()`, which - checking the [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-datetime) - is a `Dictionary`. I don't know the goal of setting `OS.get_datetime()`, but you need a different way to do it. Perhaps store it in a separate variable? - Ah, by the way, this is not a forum, this a Q&A site, and what you posted is not an answer, you can edit the question to add information.